# Does the Torah support a more Socialist or Capitalist form of government?

Tags: politics-government, public-policy

There is, of course, a [spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum) between fully [socialist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialism) to fully [capitalist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalism), however, I'm wondering what type of government the Torah supports and where it would fall on the spectrum?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40161/170 , https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27763/170

Comment: Why does it need to support any one kind?

Comment: The only successful form of government we see in Tanakh is a powerful constitutional monarchy, in which the king's power is limited by halacha, the Sandhedrin, the Kohenim, and other counterbalances. Economically speaking, praying for rain, tithing, keeping the Sabbath and Sabbatical year and not worshipping other gods are presented as the keys to prosperity for all, with gleaning in the fields and tzeddakah as a safety net for the poor.

Comment: Doesn't it support monarchy? ([Devarim 17:15](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9981/jewish/Chapter-17.htm#v=15))

Comment: These elements suggest that all parnassah comes from Hashem, with is not particularly a feature of existing governments or economic systems. You can twist the Torah's words to support capitalism, communism, theocracy, socialism, etc., but Torah government and economics are very much their own system.

Comment: I find it difficult to see the Torah supporting anything other than a monarchy with a descendant of King David in the throne...@DoubleAA